# Object reference not set to an instance of an object accessing DataGridView

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview, ado.net, nullreferenceexception

I want to transfer data from a DataGridView to another one, here is a sample of my code:

```
private void btnShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtr = new DataTable();
    dtr.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dtr.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Label", typeof(string)));
    dtr.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Domain", typeof(string)));

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow erow = dtr.NewRow();
        erow[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        erow[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        erow[2] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        dtr.Rows.Add(erow);
    }

    dataGridView2.DataSource = dtr;
 }
```

I'm still receiving `NullReferenceException` at Line 11.

Comment: What exactly does the code on line 11 look like ? In case its for accessing the cell value, do you have 3 columns (cell[2] or cell[3]) in the grid

Comment: Line 11, `erow = dtr.NewRow();` looks fine to me. Are you sure this exception throws in line 11?

Comment: Is this code running on a Postback?  Might be an issue with the ASP.NET lifecycle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One or more of your cells contains a NULL value.
You read that NULL value and then try to call the method ToString() on a NULL reference.
Of course this will fail with the mentioned exception

So, if you want to store an empty string in case of null

```
erow[0] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value == null ? 
          string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
erow[1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value == null ? 
          string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
erow[2] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value == null ? 
          string.Empty : dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();;
```